# How can I provide wi-fi access from my home's wi-fi router to a guest house?

Tags: wireless-networking

I need to provide wi-fi access to my guest house that is line-of-sight and about 300' feet away.  I want to link from the wi-fi router in my home to something like a wi-fi range extender at the guest house.  I'm trying to avoid the cost of a second ip service connection. I expect that an intermediate device may be needed at my end.  Outdoor high gain antennas may be required at each end.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a solution?

Comment: Have you considered a cable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to focus your signal a bit more you can use windsurfer or something rigged with the same principal [link1](http://www.freeantennas.com/projects/template2/index.html) [link2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=sUTT8wdN_VA). Crude, but effective. Any repeater options would need to bridge between houses (which I'm assuming is outdoors) otherwise there's really no point so the first commenter is basically correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of people getting a range of more than a mile with a setup similar to this (found on Amazon):
[image: found on amazon]

In the picture, there is an omni-directional antenna, a [Ubiquiti bullet](http://www.ubnt.com/airmax#bulletm), and another router (to produce a signal for the lower power devices that require the signal).

So, your setup could be: Your current Wi-Fi router → the Ubiquiti bullet and antenna mounted on the outside of your guest house → guest house Wi-Fi router.

Answer (score -2):

Try daisy-chaining Apple AirPort Extreme Base Stations

Comment: Could you expand on this answer a little more?

Comment: This is a little old but it should help.  http://gigaom.com/2010/03/03/how-to-setup-an-airport-extreme-in-bridge-mode/

Comment: Answers should be able to stand by themselves. It would be best to take the most important parts of that article and cite them, including the link only for reference.